# C++ Extensions for Library Fundamentals, ISO/IEC TS 19568:2017

Tags: c++

I read about new C++ features, especially those suited to replace pre-processor code in modern C++, like `std::experimental::source_location::current()`.

I found that this function (among others) is part of "Version 2 of the C++ Extensions for Library Fundamentals, ISO/IEC TS 19568:2017".

I never heard about that library before.

Which compilers do support it? Is there a way to find out if specific features actually will be part of a future C++ standard? How stable are the implementations of that extension? Is it a good idea to use it today for productive code?

Comment: If gcc, clang or VS support it out-of-the-box, then it’s good enough to use. But you need to check which ones exactly do. For checking, godbolt or any other online compiler services are available – so you should be able to answer most of this question yourself. In practice, do you really care about compilers other than those 3?

Comment: You can find out about TS features making it into an IS only by following [the committee’s progress](https://isocpp.org/blog/category/standardization) (just like for any other change).